# how do you build DTrace on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm trying to build the dtrace target in the Xcode project using the
advice here:

http://osx86.boeaja.info/2009/10/building-xnu-kernel-on-snow-leopard/

But I get:
libproc.m:24:49: error: CoreSymbolication/CoreSymbolication.h: No such
file or directory

I realize CoreSymbolication is a private framework, but Apple must
make this header available somewhere in order for me to build dtrace,
right? Can someone point me to the necessary files to build dtrace?

Comment: DTrace is build into the standard shipping kernel in Snow Leopard. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to build it from scratch. I figured that was part of the bargain with an open source (CDDL) package, but maybe Apple doesn't have to provide all the pieces to make this true?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably figured out, Apple only has to release parts of the kernel which are taken from other open-source projects, and that doesn't include the userland libraries that they build on top of the kernel. `CoreSymbolication/CoreSymbolication.h` sounds a lot like a userspace header for Obj-C though, so you can probably build the kernel DTrace utilities without it. (Although I could very well be wrong.)

I would guess it's being used for symbol identification in the userland `dtrace(1m)` command. If only there was a tool that could help us figure this out... :-D

```
# dtrace -n 'pid$target:CoreSymbolication::entry {}' -c 'dtrace -ln syscall::write:entry'
dtrace: description 'pid$target:CoreSymbolication::entry ' matched 246 probes
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
  147    syscall                                               write entry
dtrace: pid 88089 has exited
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  2   6538 CSSymbolOwnerGetRegionWithName:entry 
  2   5014 CSSymbolOwnerForeachRegionWithName:entry 
  2   5078      CSRegionForeachSymbol:entry 
  2   6495 CSSymbolicatorGetSymbolOwnerWithUUIDAtTime:entry 
  2   6493 CSSymbolicatorForeachSymbolOwnerWithUUIDAtTime:entry 
  2   6494 CSSymbolicatorForeachSymbolOwnerWithCFUUIDBytesAtTime:entry 
  2   5048  CSSymbolOwnerGetDataFlags:entry 
  2   6538 CSSymbolOwnerGetRegionWithName:entry 
  2   5014 CSSymbolOwnerForeachRegionWithName:entry 
  2   5078      CSRegionForeachSymbol:entry 
  2   5092         CSSymbolIsExternal:entry 
  2   5092         CSSymbolIsExternal:entry
  ...
```

It looks like the library is in use by the `dtrace` command, anyway.

Comment: Reverse-engineered headers available here – https://github.com/mountainstorm/CoreSymbolication (haven't tried using them myself, so no idea how good they are)